# hard coded selecting in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can someone tell me why this works in MySQL but not PostgreSQL?

```
select "hi" as ham, 1 as eggs
```

I'm trying to union a query with some hard-coded values.

Postgres says "ERROR: column "hi" does not exist Position: 8"

MySQL says the right thing.

Comment: Use `single quote` instead `double quote`.. `Postgresql` know `hi` as column not string..

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to change the " to ' double qoute to single qoute in postgress

```
select 'hi' as ham, 1 as eggs
```

Comment: that works, thanks. i'll accept this answer in 11 minutes when I'm allowed ;)

Comment: is there any deep reason for this, or just arbirary syntactical design decision?

Comment: double quotes are used to name an identifier without changing its case like you want to create table CREATE TABLE "Sample" something like that

Comment: @offwhitelotus: that's not an "arbitrary design decision". This syntax was defined by the SQL standard 30 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use single quote, not double quote.

```
Select 'hi' as ham;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to let `hi` be row value you need to use single-qoute otherwise PostgreSQL DB Engine will take it as a column.

This sample ORDER is a keyword but I can use double-qoute to escape the keyword as column name, although I didn't encourage use keyword as a column name.

```
CREATE TABLE T("ORDER" INT);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1);

SELECT "ORDER"
FROM T
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=3b2731b6c3c753dfacbd7a0bf8ea0240)

so you might use like this.

```
select 'hi' as ham, 1 as eggs
```